Using Sphinx to document Python modules that are nested in subfolders
I have been playing with Sphinx to document Python modules, and so far it works well (except for one problem; see below). Here is the script I created to automatically document and open a browser session (for testing).
#!/bin/bash

# Function to install dependencies
install_dependencies() {
    echo "Installing Sphinx..."
    pip install sphinx
    echo "Installing sphinx-rtd-theme..."
    pip install sphinx-rtd-theme
}

# Function to run sphinx-quickstart inside a sphinx directory
run_sphinx_quickstart() {
    mkdir -p sphinx  # Create sphinx directory if it doesn't exist
    cd sphinx        # Move into sphinx directory
    sphinx-quickstart --quiet --project "Teste" --author "Victor" --release "0.1" --language "pt" --sep --makefile --batchfile --extensions "sphinx.ext.autodoc,sphinx.ext.napoleon,sphinx.ext.viewcode,sphinx.ext.intersphinx,sphinx.ext.autosummary"
}

# Function to delete the current conf.py and recreate it with updated content
recreate_conf_py() {
    sphinx_path=$1  # Path to the user's provided folder

    # Navigate to the source folder where conf.py is generated
    cd source

    # Delete the existing conf.py
    rm -f conf.py

    # Create a new conf.py with the updated content
    echo "
import os
import sys
from pathlib import Path

sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('/home/dev2/odoo/odoo16/odoo-server'))
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('$sphinx_path'))  # User's provided path goes here
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('../'))
sys.path.insert(0, str(Path('..', 'src').resolve()))

autodoc_mock_imports = ['odoo', 'odoo.addons']

project = 'Teste'
copyright = '2024, Victor'
author = 'Victor'

extensions = [
    'sphinx.ext.autodoc',
    'sphinx.ext.napoleon',
    'sphinx.ext.viewcode',
    'sphinx.ext.intersphinx',
    'sphinx.ext.autosummary',
]

viewcode_line_numbers = True
templates_path = ['_templates']
exclude_patterns = ['**/__init__.py', '**/__manifest__.py']

autodoc_default_options = {
    'members': True,
    'undoc-members': True,
    'private-members': True,
    'special-members': '__init__',
    'inherited-members': True,
    'show-inheritance': True
}

language = 'pt'

html_theme = 'sphinx_rtd_theme'
html_static_path = ['_static']
" > conf.py

    echo "conf.py recreated with the provided path."
}

# Function to add 'modules' entry to index.rst
update_index_rst() {
    cd source

    # Add standard heading and 'modules' to index.rst
    echo ".. Teste documentation master file

Welcome to the Teste documentation!
===================================

.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 6
   :caption: Contents:

   modules
" > index.rst

    echo "index.rst updated with 'modules' entry."
}

# Function to generate Sphinx documentation files from the provided path
build_sphinx_files() {
    sphinx_path=$1  # Path to the user's provided folder
    cd ..
    cd sphinx
    sphinx-apidoc -f -M -o source/ $sphinx_path
    echo " you are now inside the path: $(pwd)"
    echo " you are now inside the path: $(pwd)"
    echo " you are now inside the path: $(pwd)"
    echo " you are now inside the path: $(pwd)"
    echo " you are now inside the path: $(pwd)"
    echo " you are now inside the path: $(pwd)"

    make clean
    make html

    index_file="build/html/index.html"
    if [[ -f "$index_file" ]]; then
        'google-chrome' "$index_file" &
        echo "Documentation opened in your default browser." &
        echo "Sphinx setup is complete!"
    else
        echo "Index file not found at $index_file. Please check the path."
    fi
}

# Main script execution
read -p "Enter the full path to your Odoo server directory (e.g., /home/dev2/odoo/odoo16/arxi-quality-servers/arxi-quality-client): " server_path

# Print the path with a smiley face
echo "You provided: $server_path :)"

# Install necessary dependencies (Sphinx and sphinx-rtd-theme)
install_dependencies

# Create sphinx folder and run sphinx-quickstart
run_sphinx_quickstart

# Delete and recreate conf.py with the server path provided by the user
recreate_conf_py "$server_path"

# Update index.rst to include 'modules'
update_index_rst

# Generate Sphinx documentation files for the provided server path
build_sphinx_files "$server_path"

# Go back to the original folder (parent directory)
cd ../..

echo "Sphinx setup is complete!"


My problem is that I cannot make the script acknowledge subfolders, only folders it considers a "module", which I believe reads as folders with __init__.py inside of them.
Is there a way for me to document every python module, even if it is not in an upper level folder? Here is an example:

Thank you!

Using arguments f, m, o in sphinx script
Manually changing :maxdepth: on toctree to multiple values
Adding __init__.py files to multiple subfolders (not ideal)


Unless you are working with namespace packages, you should add __init__.py files. See https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages.

You could also try the implicit-namespaces option with sphinx-apidoc.
